# UITtextView text not working only in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, uitextview

I'm working on a `iOS` app, I've tested the app of a few `iPhones` and it worked fine, there is only one problem, I have a `UITextView` in my app that works fine on devices but in the simulator it will only let me type 1 character in the textview, and sometimes none at all, it opens my keyboard up and appears like I can type but I get this problem.

Comment: clean the project, uninstall the app in the simulator, if the problem persists, post your code

Comment: On which simulator r you running that app check ios target & running simulator???

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode release notes say:

> iOS Simulator sometimes stops responding to hardware keyboard. Quitting and relaunching the simulator usually corrects this. (14642684)